# How to move the dates in the JSON so that the days collide with each other?

Tags: python, json, date

The JSON format is like this. I am performing calculations on the data for eg date 1st Jan 2017. That 1st Jan in 2017 would be a Sunday for example.  But in 2018, that 1st Jan 2018 will be a Monday. Now I know that each year these days move 1 forward. But my calculations are based on the days, for eg, i need to compare values of Mondays with Mondays not with a weekend because the factor i will calculate will be wrong if a weekday is compared to a weekend.

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import numpy as np
import json

with open('test.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
X, Y = [], []
for item in data['Elements']:
    for sub_item in item['TimeSpans']:
        if (item['Date'].startswith("2017")):
            X.append(sub_item['TimeSpan']+" "+ item['Date'])        #2017
            Y.append(sub_item['Value'])

X1, Y1 = [], []
for item in data['Elements']:
    for sub_item in item['TimeSpans']:
        if (item['Date'].startswith("2018")):
            X1.append(sub_item['TimeSpan']+" "+ item['Date'])       #2018
            Y1.append(sub_item['Value'])
diff = []

for i in range(len(Y)):

    if(Y[i]==0):
        diff.append(1)
    if(Y1[i]==0):
        diff.append(1)
    else:
        var = Y[i] / Y1[i] 
        diff.append(var)
#print(diff[0])



XP=[]
YP=[]
for k in range(len(Y1)): #len(diff)
    if (Y1[k]==0):
        YP.append(Y1[k])
    if (diff[k]==0):
        YP.append(Y1[k])
    var2 =   Y1[k]/diff[k] 
    YP.append(var2)



for item in data['Elements']:
    for sub_item in item['TimeSpans']:
        if (item['Date'].startswith("2019")):
            XP.append(sub_item['TimeSpan']+" "+ item['Date'])       #2019
```

```
{
    "SpotKey": "79",
    "SpotName": "ELIX",
    "Denomination": "eur/mwh",
    "Elements": [
      {
        "Date": "2017-01-01T00:00:00",
        "Base": 36.8696,
        "Peak": 36.0125,
        "TimeSpans": [
          {
            "TimeSpan": "00:00-01:00",
            "Value": 46.43
          },
          {
            "TimeSpan": "01:00-02:00",
            "Value": 42.43
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Date": "2017-01-02T00:00:00",
        "Base": 53.7413,
        "Peak": 63.0317,
        "TimeSpans": [
          {
            "TimeSpan": "00:00-01:00",
            "Value": 41.18
          },
          {
            "TimeSpan": "01:00-02:00",
            "Value": 37.34
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

So here I am trying to predict the data from from 2019 and visualizing it using plotly. How do i overcome this date with day matching problem?

```py
Date=[]
for item in data['Elements']:
    for sub_item in item['TimeSpans']:
        if (item['Date'].startswith("2017")):
            iso_day = datetime.datetime.strptime(item['Date'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').isocalendar()       #Moving Date Logic
            iso_day[2] == 1
            Date.append(iso_day)

for loop in range(len(Date)):
    print(Date[loop])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem for *fiscal* years. It has been defined in ISO 8601 since 1971 as the *ISO week date* convention (*). In this convention, a day is represented as a triple (year, week number, weed day number). The first week of a year (week 01) is (equivalent definitions):

- the first week with a majority (4 or more) of its days in January.
- the one for which first day is the Monday nearest to 1 January.
- the one that has 4 January in it.

The good news is that Python datetime module knows about it:

> date.isocalendar() :
>   Return a 3-tuple, (ISO year, ISO week number, ISO weekday).

If you convert your dates with that:

```
iso_day = datetime.datetime.strptime(item['Date'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').isocalendar()
```

`iso_day[0]` will be the appropriate year, and you should control that first days observes `iso_day[2] == 1` to start with a Monday and eventually ignore previous days.

---

References on wikipedia:

- [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
- [ISO week date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date)

Comment: How would I add the Iso day to 1? i did some edits to my post to update this logic as seen above, it still starts with a:
(2016, 52, 7)
(2016, 52, 7)
(2016, 52, 7)
(2017, 1, 1)
(2017, 1, 1)